# How to I align my picture and content together? Everything keeps getting seperated

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to coding and have been at this for more than an hour. I've been trying to align everything horizontally and its keeps stacking vertically or completely separating

[image: screen shot of web page]

```css
#ourMission{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-self: left;
}

#missionPic{
  background-image: url("/public/assets/pictures/katrina-wright-yMg_SMqfoRU-unsplash.jpg");
 height: 400px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 
}

#sectionTwo{
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: inline;
```

```html
 <div id="sectionTwo" class="row flex-container">
    <div data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-duration="2500">
            <div id="ourMission" class="col-9">
                <h1>Our Mission</h1>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id
                  asperiores officiis odit illo consectetur magni ab ducimus quo
                  libero error repudiandae doloremque, quae earum necessitatibus
                  voluptate suscipit commodi. Laborum, voluptatem!</p>
                <div id="missionPic" class="col-5"></div>
              </div> 
              
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: It seems to be horizontal in your snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure how you want the layout to look, but if you use justify-content it should sort out the spacing issue

```css
#ourMission{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

If you want to see more uses for the justify-content attribute you can check out this link: [Justify Content| CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#missionPic {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589890378235-fc687148d173?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60");
  height: 400px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#sectionTwo {
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="sectionTwo" class="row flex-container">
<div data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-duration="2500">
  <div id="ourMission" class="col-9">
    <h1>Our Mission</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id
      asperiores officiis odit illo consectetur magni ab ducimus quo
      libero error repudiandae doloremque, quae earum necessitatibus
      voluptate suscipit commodi. Laborum, voluptatem!</p>
    <div id="missionPic" class="col-5">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```